# Apply link on dropdown menu but drop down menu not work in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need help : My site is non responsive desktop view is fine but when i checked drop down menu on mobile its on click redirect another page and drop down menu not open.

Is that possible working fine in mobile and desktop both. here is [link](http://crayonsinfoway.com/demo/test/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a quick tip, please add some relevant code, not just a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that in `mobile` `hover` event isn't triggered.

So manually triggering it on `click` might help:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/menu.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".menu").flexymenu({speed: 400}); //Your Original Code
    $('.menu a').bind('click', function(e) {  // Code to trigger `hover` and preventing link from opening
        $(this).trigger('hover');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

---

Here is [**`DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4ry6/)

---

It also works on `mobile` here is output:

[image: Output]

---

Also for your script after adding my code:

[image: Your codes output]

Hope it'll help you. Cheers :)!!